# CMake function to convert string to C string literal

Tags: cmake

Is there a *built-in* function to convert a string to a C string literal. For example:

```
set(foo [[Hello\ World"!\]])
convert_to_cstring_literal(bar "${foo}")
message("${foo}") # Should print (including quotes): "Hello\\ World\"!\\"
```

I mean I can do this with considerable effort with regexes, but if there's a built-in function it would be a lot nicer.

Comment: You can *almost* use the `ESCAPE_QUOTES` option on `string(CONFIGURE` but it [doesn't escape backslashes](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/3c0de6db2d9e0580f23cc95c4a1e00a8f66108c9/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx#L208).

Comment: Do we talk about pre-processor definitions? They are automatically escaped (see [policy CMP0005](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0005.html)). Otherwise would something from [`CPack.cmake`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CPack.cmake#L351) would suffice: `string(REGEX REPLACE "([\\\$\"])" "\\\\\\1" escaped "${value}")`?

Comment: It *is* a preprocessor definition, but unfortunately I have to write it to a header and use `configure_file()` because [you can't reliably pass them on the command line](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_dir/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS). Also my definition contains several C strings; it is an array initialiser list like this: `{ "foo", "bar" }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Slightly modifying the CMake's function `_cpack_escape_for_cmake` from [`CPack.cmake`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CPack.cmake#L351) I was able to successfully test the following:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(CStringLiteral)

function(convert_to_cstring_literal var value)
    string(REGEX REPLACE "([\\\$\"])" "\\\\\\1" escaped "${value}")
    set("${var}" "\"${escaped}\"" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

set(foo [[Hello\ World"!\]])

convert_to_cstring_literal(bar "${foo}")
message("${bar}") # prints "Hello\\ World\"!\\"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I actually gave up on this an used a different trick: C++ raw string literals. It's not 100% guaranteed of course, so don't use it on untrusted input (not sure why you would have any in CMake though). But it should be fine for most purposes.

```
set(foo "R\"#?#:#?#(${foo})#?#:#?#\"")
```

Comment: Why did you choose `#?#:#?#` as delimiter for the C++ raw string? Just curious, but looks kinda confusing to me.

Comment: It can be anything. I used `?` since it can't appear in Windows paths, and the string I am using is a path. But mostly it is just a crazy random string that I hope nobody ever actually puts in `foo`. If they do things will break (hence why I said "it's not 100%".